# Keep getting "no file selected" when attempting to upload an image using carrier wave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am trying to implement uploading images with CarrierWave by following this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?view=comments , but whenever I submit the image it my error message just says no file selected, when I am clearly selecting a file.

I've checked over my code many, many times and I can't figure it out.

Here is my products/new.html.erb

```
<h1> new product </h1>
<% @product = Product.new %>
<% form_for(@product) html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<% if @product.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %>
    prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
    <ul>
  <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :title %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :description %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.file_field :image %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image url" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

Here is what is in my product model:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

My new, create, and show actions from products controller:

```
def new
@product = Product.new(params[:id])
end

def create
@product = Product.new(product_params)

if @product.save
    redirect_to @product
else
    render :new
end
end

def show
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

defining params in products controller:

```
private
def product_params
params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :image, :remote_image_url)
end 
end
```

This is all the relevant info I can think of.  Thanks for the help.

Edit: After setting multipart I get this error

syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end form_for(@product) html => { :multipart => true } do |f| ^ app/views/products/new.html.erb:3: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end

I have added <% end %> tags in and I still get the same.  I posted the whole view files code above.

Comment: some stuff seems a little off in your code (perhaps on purpose but just checking): (1) new method dose not take an id input from url coz .. it's new .. not yet born object (2) usually but not necessarily form view lives in a partial

Comment: Okay, I don't think changing either of these solves my problem though.

Comment: is your form multipart? you did not post the full form so I cannot tell but for file uploads you must set `multipart: true`

Comment: as @engineersmnky said, it looks like you forgot to set the multipart sentence in your form

Comment: I tried to set up multipart, but I am getting errors..I edited the question to show the entire current view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with following form, your form looks messy, lot of end statements

## products_controller.rb

```
  def new
     @product = Product.new
  end
```

## products/new.html.erb

```
<h1> new product </h1>
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
    <% if @product.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %>
                prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
             <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :title %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>

   <div class="field">
       <%= f.file_field :image %>
   </div>

   <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "or image url" %><br />
       <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url %>
   </div>

   <div class="actions">
       <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: I need it to be a multipart form

Comment: u wont need to add that, if u are using carrierwave. I have done it thousands of time without adding enctype.