# One of my rails navbar links doesn't show up, but the rest do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can not get my new blogs link to show up in my navigation bar. I am doing the same thing as I always do and my links always work.  I have tried doing new_blogs_path new_blog_path and specifying the controller and action.

Here is my navigation links partial:

```
<%= link_to "About", controller: "static", action: "about", id: @about %>
<%= link_to "Testimonials", controller: "static", action: "testimonials", id:     

@testimonials %>
<%= link_to "Store", controller: "products", action: "index" %>
<%= link_to "New Product", new_product_path %>


<% if current_user %>
  <%link_to "New Blog", new_blog_path %>
  <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path %>
  <%= current_user.email %>.

<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %> 
  <%= link_to "Log In", login_path %>
 <% end %>
```

The new blog code can be found in the if/else statement.  Thanks for the help.

Answer my other question here too: [Keep getting "no file selected" when attempting to upload an image using carrier wave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25811508/keep-getting-no-file-selected-when-attempting-to-upload-an-image-using-carrier)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `<%= link_to "New Blog", new_blog_path %>`

Use `<%=` when you want it to be visible to the user.  Otherwise, use `<%` without an equals sign.